# Python Obtain count of lines in multiples of 64

Tags: python, file, count

Didn't quite understand how to do this enough to Google properly. I'm trying to iterate over a list which contains lines from an input file. I am keeping track of the line number for each line for error logging purposes.

I would like to write the results of my loop to an output file. I have placed the newline character to my list.append function call and it works great to determine if there is something wrong with one of the lines in the file. After each iteration it writes to a newline.

In blocks of 64 i would like to then write two newline characters to they are distinguishable in the output file. Here is what I have so far.

```
import sys

fname = sys.argv[1]
list = []
output = "hashes.txt"
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    num_line = 0
    for line in content:
        if line:    
            num_line += 1
            line = line.split(',')
            try:
                //if num_line == 64??? Not Sure how to iterate in blocks of 64\\
                list.append(line[1] + "\n\n")
            except Exception, ex:
                print("Problem on line", line, num_line)

with open(output, 'w') as w:
    w.writelines(list)
```

Comment: You could use the modulus operator, but there are better ways; give me a minute.

Comment: you only want the line number to increase if its not an empty line?

Comment: Use modulus, reset the counter every time it hits 64, whatever.

Comment: So you want to write the second comma-delimited item of each line to it's own line in the output file, plus an extra newline every 64 lines so they're separated in the output?

Comment: Not that complex. I just want the loop to know that if the counter hits a multiple of 64, then add to newline chars instead of one.

Comment: But what your script is doing is what I said, right?

Comment: actually that is exactly what I want after re-reading your comment :)

Comment: Also, your current code does `if line:`, but that'll always pass because all lines (except maybe the last) will have a `'\n'` in them. I assume you want to check if it has non-whitespace characters, so I'll make the code do that.

Comment: What do you want to do if a line.split(',')[1] is an empty string?

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
//if num_line == 64??? Not Sure how to iterate in blocks of 64\\
```

You are looking for this:

```
if not num_line % 64:
```

When the remainder of the line number divided by 64 is zero, it will go into that `if` block.

Oh, and you want `#` for Python comments, not `//`.

And as Cyphase mentioned, you'll want `if line.strip():` instead of just `if line:`, because linefeeds count as a character.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are going to process the lines later, you can read and write at the same time, without having to store the lines. Also `list` is a poor choice for a variable name as its the name of a built-in method `list()`.

You also have a try/catch that won't raise any exceptions, try this version of your code:

```
import sys

fname = sys.argv[1]
# list = [] -- not needed
output = "hashes.txt"
with open(fname) as f, open(output, 'w') as out:
    num_line = 0
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():    
            num_line += 1
            bits = line.strip().split(',')
            try:
                output_line = bits[1]
            except IndexError:
                print("Problem on line", line, num_line)
                continue # skip the rest of the loop,
                         # go to the next line
            if not num_line % 64:
                out.write('{}\n\n'.format(output_line))
            else:
                out.write('{}\n'.format(output_line))
```

Comment: The predicate with the modulus needs a `not` (or switch the `if..elif` content).

Answer (score 0):

This script should do the same thing as what you want yours to do, except it's a lot cleaner IMHO:

```
import sys

from itertools import zip_longest


# From itertools recipes:
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)


def main(outfile_path, infile_path, group_size):
    with open(infile_path) as infile, open(outfile_path) as outfile:
        # Filter out lines with zero non-whitespace characters
        nonempty_lines = (line for line in infile if line.strip())

        # Filter out lines that don't have a second value
        splittable_lines = (line for line in nonempty_lines if ',' in line)

        # Get second values from lines that have one
        all_values = (line.split(',')[1] for line in splittable_lines)

        # Filter out empty second values
        nonempty_values = (value for value in all_values if values)

        # Create output lines
        output_lines = ('{}\n'.format(value) for value in nonempty_values)

        for group_of_output_lines in grouper(output_lines, group_size):
            outfile.writelines(group_of_output_lines)
            outfile.write('\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(outfile_path='hashes.txt', infile_path=sys.argv[1], group_size=64)
```

`grouper()` is a generator that will yield tuples containing groups of `n` items from `iterable`, which we use to group by 64 items.

`main()` is pretty well-commented, so I won't explain it here unless someone finds something to be unclear.

Comment: This will raise an exception if the line just has no comma

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, `'foo,'.split(',')` returns `['foo', '']`. Those empty values are then filtered out.

Comment: Ah right, but that's just too convoluted to avoid an exception.

Comment: Seems pretty simple to me :).